# How can I convert any audio file to an .ogg in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, converters, ogg

I'm creating a C# winforms application in Visual Studio, and the user is going to upload *any* audio file that is then automatically converted to an ogg file and placed in a certain directory.

Are there any DLLs or something similar that can do this conversion? I've visited Alvas.Audio, but I'm going to be distributing this application and that's against their license.

I'm also pretty new to C# programming and pretty much taught it to myself, so I need pretty specific instructions, sorry.

Any help?

Comment: You can use BASS.NET library @ http://www.un4seen.com/

Comment: @Aybe I'll try it out, but I'm not sure if it can support conversions. I'll get back to you.